# Am I using the word "will" correctly?

Tags: word-usage

> As this is a simple name change, our address and phone number will remain the same.

Is the usage of the word *will* correct?

Comment: You might also enjoy our sister site: [ell.se]

Comment: Yes, it's correct. And _will_ is entirely appropriate for a formal notification like this.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is grammatical, clear and idiomatic English.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The usage of will is absolutely fine. But using *change of name* in the sentence sounds more formal in place of **name change**